# Not able to play the raw file in Android?

Tags: android, file-descriptor

I tried the below code to play the mp3 file but it plays all the ringtones.
Can anyone help me why the ringtone is being played?

```
            MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
            AssetFileDescriptor fd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.dialtone);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fd.getFileDescriptor());



            mMediaPlayer1.setDataSource(in.getFD());

            mMediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer1.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer1.start();`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void startSound(Context context, int soundResId) {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundResId);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

then

```
startSound(this, R.raw.dialtone);
```